# Filter out a date range from a yearmon variable in R

Tags: date, range, filtering, zoo

The `yearmon` class from the `zoo` package seems particularly useful for working with data that only has a year and month, but no day or time. However, I find it difficult to work with, particularly when trying to filter out a range of dates.

`yearmon` is kind of a weird data class. It displays dates like `Jun 2002`. This is more aesthetically pleasing, but (correct me if I'm wrong) underneath it's the year and a fraction of the month, with January being `0` and December being `11`. So, `Jun 2002`, for example, would actually be `2002.417` (i.e., 5/12) under the hood.

Let's assume now that you have monthly data over a ten year period (2000-2009), kinda like this.

```
       date  value
   <yearmon> <dbl>
 1 Jan 2000  10000
 2 Feb 2000  30000
 3 Mar 2000    250
 4 Apr 2000     20
 5 May 2000  50000
 6 Jun 2000 -90042
 7 Jul 2000  73400
 8 Aug 2000   4317
 9 Sep 2000   1000
10 Oct 2000    -22
```

You want to filter out rows that fall between June 2002 and November 2003 and keep everything else in your data set.

`%in%` is good for keeping only a specific range of values, but I often find taking the inverse of this function just as useful, like the following.

```
%!in% <- Negate(%in%)
```

My understanding is that you can't work with what `yearmon` displays. Meaning, you can't actually reference dates like `"Jun 2003"`, but instead you need to work with what's stored under the hood (i.e., `2002.417`). I would think it'd be sufficient to use `filter()` from `dplyr` to filter out the date range through something like the following

```
my_data |>
  filter(date %!in% c(2002.417:2003.833))
```

However, I find that this doesn't seem to work, as the months from June 2002 to November 2003 won't be removed. I think it might have something to do with the colon not working with `yearmon` somehow? I tried only removing June 2002 (i.e., removed the colon and 2003.833) and it was able to remove that single date. However, I find it doesn't like it when you try to specify a range of dates to remove. If the dates were numeric, say, written as `200206` and `200311`, I've found that running my above code works in removing that period.

Does anyone know how to filter out a range of dates in class `yearmon`? I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to be much stuff about filtering out date ranges (usually I find online tutorials only show how to keep a specific range, rather than exclude).

Also, because I don't see a lot of discussion on it either, what are peoples thoughts on the `yearmon` class from `zoo`? Do you find it useful? Many tutorials only seem to use `yearmon` for extracting month or year into a separate column. Am I wrong from keeping dates with only a month and year in class `yearmon`? Is it better to store them as class `date` and just add `01` at the end for the day so it's like `2002-06-01`?

I've tried using !=, instead of %!in%. I also tried feeding in c("Jun 2002": "Nov 2003") but I get an NA/NAN error message. I've also tried converting it to a `date` class and using c("2002-06-01:"2003-11-01") but I think I also got a NA/NAN error, even after dropping the quotation marks and swapping the hyphens for slashes c("2002/06/01:"2003/11/01"). I also tried dropping the concatenate sign and brackets in case the numeric date values were sufficient, but that didn't work either. I also tried playing with the Negate of the `between()` function, but found that it didn't work and was making the code more complicated than it ought to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used `yearmon` before, but I believe your error is stemming from the use of `:`. Using a colon like `2000:2003` will produce integer values from 2000 to 2003.
Using non-integer values increments by 1 until the end point is exceeded. This would not produce the desired matches in your situation.

```r
c(2002.417:2003.833)
[1] 2002.417 2003.417
```

The function you are looking for is [`seq()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/seq).

```r
 x <- seq(from = 2002.417, to = 2003.833, by = 1/12)
 x
 [1] 2002.417 2002.500 2002.584 2002.667 2002.750 2002.834 2002.917 2003.000 2003.084
[10] 2003.167 2003.250 2003.334 2003.417 2003.500 2003.584 2003.667 2003.750

 as.yearmon(x)
 [1] "Jun 2002" "Jul 2002" "Aug 2002" "Sep 2002" "Oct 2002" "Nov 2002" "Dec 2002"
 [8] "Jan 2003" "Feb 2003" "Mar 2003" "Apr 2003" "May 2003" "Jun 2003" "Jul 2003"
[15] "Aug 2003" "Sep 2003" "Oct 2003"
```

You'll notice `Nov 2003` (or `2003+((11-1)/12) = 2003.834`) is missing. This is because `seq()` cannot exceed the `to` parameter. Increasing the `to` parameter by a small amount will remedy that issue.

Using the appropriate `seq()` call in place of `c()` in your `filter()` should return the correct subset of data.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! Interestingly, it didn't seem to want to work until I wrapped the whole thing around an `as.yearmon` function, like you showed, then it worked. This seemed funny to me at first, because the variable date was already in class `yearmon`. I guess it had something to do with putting it back into `yearmon` with `as.yearmon`, since using the under the hood value (i.e., `2002.417`) is numeric. So, it ended up looking like this:

`my_data |> filter(date %!in% as.yearmon(seq(from = 2002.417, to = 2003.834, by = 1/12))`

Thanks again!

Comment: @johnny_gillette Interesting, but I suppose that makes sense. I'm happy to help. If you could accept my answer to close the question, it would be much appreciated. :)